# Saving input data JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to programming and am taking a class on OOP. I am trying to come up with a JavaFX application that saves mood input to be able to gather data. As of now the data is having to the console command window, but gets replaced when a new input is added. any Direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class comboBoxPTSD extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Scene scene;
    Button button;
    ComboBox<String> comboBox;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("PTSD Tracker App");
        button = new Button("Submit");

        comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll(
                "Happy", "Content", "Good", "Sad", "Angry", 
            "Hopeless", "Suicidal");

        //sets combo boxes text name. 
        comboBox.setPromptText("How are you doing today?");
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        /*
         * can set the comboBox to input user input with 
        *"comboBox.setEditable(true);"
        *will override box name. 
        *want to save input and output...
        *
        *use variable string.
        */
        button.setOnAction(e -> printMood());

        //ComboBoxes also generate actions if you need to get value instantly
        comboBox.setOnAction( e -> System.out.println("User selected " + comboBox.getValue()) );

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
        layout.getChildren().addAll(comboBox, button);

        scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    private void printMood(){
        System.out.println(comboBox.getValue());
    }


}
```

[Application JavaFX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdqME.png)

[Consol picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsv9c.png)

Comment: And what are your expectations? Should the moods be saved to a file? Displayed in some kind of list? What if few days passed and the mood didn't change — should there be several the same moods records or probably mood with current date? What you need is a better specification.

Comment: You have to come up with some type of schema. It can be something as simple as `user mood=happy`. It can be something more complicate. You then need to find a way to save the data so that it can be retrieved later. A simple way is a text file where each line holds data for a different user. A more complicated way is to use a database. Sqlite is a good place to start. If the data does not need to be available when the program ends and runs again, try using a `Map` or `List` of `User`objects

Comment: First off thank you for your input. I am learning as I go, and I now know that I need more of a plain for the result. I would like to compile a list into a text file for later adding a share feedback button within the GUI to show the doctor a list of moods and or notes from days and hours. so, I am going to need to add input from the clock and calendar, for date and time when the moods are selected. this is more focused on a single individual so adding different mood trackers for different users is not where I am focused as of now. Currently i am looking up adding the list option to the app.